# Force viewDidLoad to run again on start

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

In my app there is only one "scene".

All the UI is loaded from the storyboard but the user can then change this by changing fonts, colours, positions, etc...

I'd like this to reset when the user closes the app so that it's back to default when they start it.

Is there a way to reload the view from the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set a reuse identifier to your controllers in your storyboard, you can call :
`[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Name"]`

Answer (score 2):

Use
`-viewWillAppear`
that is the purpose of it

> -initWithFrame:
>
> If you use Interface Builder to design your interface, this method is
> not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib
> file. Objects in a nib file are reconstituted and then initialized
> using their initWithCoder: method, which modifies the attributes of
> the view to match the attributes stored in the nib file.

Comment: But how can I use viewWillAppear to reload the default UI elements from the storyboard?

Comment: again, this method is called FROM the storyboard. I'd like to know how to trigger this.

Comment: Yes, I understand the docs. I'm not asking which function to put stuff in. I'm asking how do I ask the viewController to go back to the NIB/Storyboard and reload the view from what is set in that nib/storyboard. i.e. I have a label with white text. The user changes it to red. How do I reload the view (from the nib) so that the text is white again. It seems stupid to have all my UI done in IB and then redo it all in code.

Comment: make it in programmatically code and set it .I don't think there is an another option.

Answer (score 0):

from the method in your appdelegate

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

call the viewdidload of your controller

as this method of appdelegate is called whenever your app comes from background to foreground